# .pfx cert to DER encoded binary X.509

Tags: ssl-certificate, x509certificate, client-certificates, pfx

I am attempting to export a .pfx certificate. But I am not able to export it along with the private keys.  The option to export along with private key is greyed out with a note that stated the "associated private key is marked as not exportable".

screenshot of the greyed out part (https://i.stack.imgur.com/OVNXg.png)

I attempted to use Windows Cert Manager to import the .pfx and then from cert mngr I tried to export the Root, Intermediate, and Client certificates to DER encoded binary x.509 (.CER).  I also tried various methods using OpenSSL to convert the .pfx to .der, .cer, or .p7b. Unfortunately, I have had no luck. All the openssl commands have converted .pfx cert to my desired format but when I upload it to webMethods tool I encountered various errors such as:

Certificate chain contains a single certificate, and that certificate is not self-signed: Even though I converted the whole chain to .cer/p7b and tried importing to sign/verify, encrypt/decrypt, and SSL.
Java Null pointer.
Cannot convert byte[][] to X509Certificate[], exception encountered at index 0. CertificateException encountered; Trading Networks cannot convert byte[] to java.security.cert.X509Certificat - Tried to import .cer that was exported from .pfx.

My end goal is to convert the .pfx file along with the private keys to .der/cer/.p7b. And then copy the individual Root, Intermediate and client certs.

Comment: You are using the Windows certificate manager so you have first imported the certificate and private key into the users certificate store. If in the import process the key was no imported with the "allow export" checkbox enabled then you can do what you want, Windows won't allow you to export the private key. But the question is still why you tried to import it instead of using Openssl or KeyStoreExplorer or KeyTool to modify the PFX/PCKS#12 keystore you have.